# Allowing inputs to be matrix or vectors or scalar in octave

Tags: matrix, vector, octave

I am doing the coursera machine learning logistic regression assignment and I wrote the top piece of code.

Instructions

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
%SIGMOID Compute sigmoid functoon
%   J = SIGMOID(z) computes the sigmoid of z.

% You need to return the following variables correctly 
g = zeros(size(z));

% ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
% Instructions: Compute the sigmoid of each value of z (z can be a matrix,
%               vector or scalar).



g = (1 / (1 + exp(-1 * z)) ) .^ 1;

%g = (1 + exp(-1 * z)) .^ -1;
% =============================================================

end
```

My Code --- Breaks when inputting a vector or matrix

```
g = (1 / (1 + exp(-1 * z)) ) .^ 1;
```

I found this code on some github ---- Works for all cases

```
g = (1 + exp(-1 * z)) .^ -1;
```

The issue is the output works when my input is a scalar. My code breaks when it becomes a vector. May i know what am i missing as it appears to me to be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `/` which is a [matrix right division](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Arithmetic-Ops.html#XREFmrdivide) to be an [element-wise division (`./`)](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Arithmetic-Ops.html#XREFrdivide)

```
g = (1 ./ (1 + exp(-1 * z)) ) .^ 1;
```

The use of `/` will work just fine for scalars, but when one of the inputs is a matrix (in this case the right side of the operator), [the meaning changes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Left_and_right_division) and you will get either an error or unexpected results.